# input data codeigniter always 0 on database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I found the problem.
I have read on [CodeIgniter Form always sends '0' data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984328/codeigniter-form-always-sends-0-data) and [Zero (0 ) Database Result in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858441/zero-0-database-result-in-codeigniter) but it did not help.
the problem data in the database is always 0.

my add view code

```
<form method="post">
        <div class="form-inline form-group">
        <label for="kegiatan">Kegiatan : </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="disableSelect" disabled><option>MPAB</option></select> <!-- inget ganti pake id terakhir -->
    </div>      

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="indikator">Indikator : </label>
                <input type="text" name="indikator" id="indikator" placeholder="Indikator" class="form-control"> <!-- kosongin, tapi kalo edit munculin indikator yang di edit -->
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <a href="<?= base_url() ?>ipmpab/addIpMpabDb/" class="btn btn-success"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> add</a>
    </div>
    </form>
```

my controller

```
        public function addIpMpabDb() {
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==true){
        $tambah = array (
                'indikator' =>$this->input->post('indikator'),
                'id_jk'=>1
    );
            $this->tb_det_penilaian->addIndikator($tambah);
    redirect("ipmpab");
    }
```

my model

```
    function addIndikator($tambah)
{
    $this->db->insert('tb_det_penilaian', $tambah);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a valid submit button in your html code.
Remove your link and use an input type "submit" or a button

**Replace :**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="<?= base_url() ?>ipmpab/addIpMpabDb/" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> add
    </a>
</div>
```

**With :**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>add 
    </button>
</div>
```

... For exemple

Then add the action attribute to the form :

```
<form method="post" action="<?= site_url('ipmpab/addIpMpabDb'); ?>">
```